# Exact meaning of ing form

Tags: present-participles

I've heard expressions like this:

> 1: *I was born **forgiving** you.*
>    2: *I was born **to forgive** you.*

What if any difference is there between these?

Comment: *content* is singular here!

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What difference does it make to you whether ***forgiving*** in your example is called a gerund? In fact, it's *not* - since a gerund is a verb form *functioning as a noun*, which clearly is not the case here. The difference between using the present participle and the infinitive is that ***forgiving*** describes *what you were doing at the time you were born* (and possibly ever since), but ***to forgive*** describes *the **purpose** for which you were born* (which you may or may not have yet started to do).

Comment: @user10222: Of course. But you still haven't answered *my* question. Are you asking about the difference between identifying a usage as present participle or gerund, or about the difference between using ***forgiving*** and ***to forgive*** in your example sentence?

Comment: @FumbleFingers i guess latter one was my intention i was just wondering about in what situations would them be used and natural. I was going too far away alone sorry my question seems to have been beside the point

Comment: @@user10222: I've extended someone else's "edit awaiting approval" to clarify what I *think* you're asking. If I've got it wrong you can reverse the edit, but I did this because there's already one "closevote" saying the question is "Unclear". Following my edit, the question might be a *duplicate* (I haven't checked), but at least it shouldn't get closed as Unclear.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  i really appreciate what you've done . And i didn't know that editing others question would be possible. Thanks for making up for my poor question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers my comment was for the original question (before being edited) where the OP used a plural word. And for your comment, I fully agree!

Comment: @Maluk: My apologies - either my eyes are getting old, or my screen is too small. Having read your *content* as *context*, I unthinkingly assumed your comment was asking for more of the latter (where actually what we needed was clarification as to whether OP was asking about grammatical terminology or semantic distinctions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OP's examples, #1 uses the present participle *(**forgiving**)*, and #2 uses the infinitive *(**forgive**)*. You might think the infinitive is *"**to** forgive"*, but this is misleading.

It's actually a [**bare** (**unmarked**) infinitive](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/verbs/infin2.htm). The preceding ***to*** is a preposition - which as usual, has the general sense of *in the direction of, towards, for the purpose of*. Specifically here it's probably easiest to understand it as being a shortened form of ***in order to***. Thus, OP's example #2...

> *I was born to **forgive** you.*
> =
> *The **reason** I was born was **in order to** forgive you*.

---

In OP's context, the continuous verb form ***forgiving*** can never have that sense of "purpose". It could only ever describe *something I was doing at the same time as I was being born* - as in, for example,...

> [*I was born **kicking** and **screaming***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20born%20kicking%20and%20screaming%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22I%20was%20born%20kicking%20and%20screaming%22)
> =
> *I was kicking and screaming **while/during the time when** I was being born*

Since babies are obviously not capable of "forgiving" whilst being born, OP's #1 is effectively nonsense.

Comment: I agree, but note that "I was born forgiving you" does still work if it's hyperbole for poetic/emphatic purposes. I can imagine it being used in an emotional exchange: "I'm so sorry. Can you forgive me?" "I was BORN forgiving you!"